# Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/disabledeploys app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I was invited as a collaborator to a Rails app deployed in Heroku. I cloned the app, made a few changes and then committed to git and tried to push to Heroku but I am getting that error message.

Any ideas about this "Ruby/disabledeploys app"? I already tried to google about it but had no luck..

The full message I get after the `git push heroku master` command:

```
-----> Ruby/DisableDeploys app detected
!
!     Ruby deploys have been temporarily disabled. We will have more information 
available shortly, including a workaround.
!
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/disabledeploys app

To git@heroku.com:salty-temple-5503.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:salty-temple-5503.git'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the heroku status page for more info, which is here:
http://status.heroku.com

This particular incident is detailed here:
https://status.heroku.com/incidents/489

Heroku disabled deploys because rubygems.org has been compromised. You can get more info on that here:
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5139583

(There was a status/news page directly on the rubygems.org domain, but it's now returning a 404.)

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan! I looked at Heroku's twitter, blog and news section - I guess I should have considered looking for a "status" page as well. Thanks again!